# How to run a function when the Kivy window is un-minimised

Tags: python, kivy, window

I have an app that has a see through window-
[image]

and when it un-minimised, I would like to take a screenshot to update the image but I don't know how to run a function when the window un-minimises.

I have tried

```
from io import BytesIO

from PIL import ImageGrab
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.core.image import Image as CoreImage
from kivy.core.window import Window as CoreWindow
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.app import App


class Widget(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        CoreWindow.bind(left=self.on_pos, top=self.on_pos)

        Clock.schedule_once(self.take_screenshot, 0)

    def on_pos(self, _, pos):
        self.ids["parentScreenImage"].pos = 0 - CoreWindow.left, \
                                            (CoreWindow.top + CoreWindow.height) - self.ids["parentScreenImage"].size[1]

    def take_screenshot(self, _=None):
        img = ImageGrab.grab()
        data = BytesIO()
        img.save(data, format='png')
        data.seek(0)
        img = CoreImage(BytesIO(data.read()), ext='png')

        self.ids["parentScreenImage"].texture = img.texture
        self.ids["parentScreenImage"].size = img.size
        self.ids["parentScreenImage"].pos = 0 - CoreWindow.left, 0 - CoreWindow.top


class app(App):
    def on_unminimise(self):
        print("worked with on_unminimise")

    def on_un_minimise(self):
        print("worked with on_un_minimise")

    def on_resume(self):  # I think this only works on a phone
        print("worked with on_resume")

    def build(self):
        return Widget()


Builder.load_string("""
<Widget>:
    Image:
        id: parentScreenImage

        size_hint: None, None
""")
app().run()
```

but nothing gets printed.
There also seems to be nothing on google either. Please help.

P.S. Out of interest, how would you run it when the window minimises

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can bind to the `on_show` event:

```
class app(App):
    def on_show(self, window):
        print('show', window)

    def build(self):
        CoreWindow.bind(on_show=self.on_show)
        return Widget()
```

Comment: By the way, I don't think defining your own `Widget` class is a good idea.

Comment: Thanks, It was just bc I had no idea what to name the class in the example.